# How exactly works this JPA mapping?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubt related this **JPA** example finded on the course slides:

There are 2 entity classes that maps 2 tables:

1) **Customer** entity class that map the **T_CUSTOMER** DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= “T_CUSTOMER”)
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column (name=“cust_id”)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn (name=“cid”)
    private Set<Address> addresses;
    …
    …
    …
}
```

2) **Address** entity class that map the **T_ADDRESS** DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= “T_ADDRESS”)
public class Address {

    @Id private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String suburb;
    private String city;
    private String postcode;
    private String country;

}
```

So I have 2 doubts related to this provided example:

1) Why into the **Address** class there are no **@Column** annotation? Maybe JPA use the property name for the matching with the DB table column name for defaut if it is not provided by the **@Column** annotation?

2) As you can see in the previouse example the **Customer** entity class contains this field that represent a **One To Many** relation

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn (name=“cid”)
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

So I think that it means that at one row of the **T_CUSTOMER** table are associated more rows of the **T_ADDRESS** table and that these rows are represented as a collection of **Address** model instances. Is it right?

Now my doubt is that the join is done using the **cid** name. This name not appear as a property of my **Address** class. So what is it? Is it the name of a column belonging to the **T_ADDRESS** and that is not mapped by the entity class **Address**?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Why into the Address class there are no *@Column* annotation?**

The **@Column** annotation is optional. By default, If you are not annotating your fields/properties of your Bean/Entity class with **@Column** then **ORM** provider (e.g. **Hibernate**) will create a table for the corresponding Bean/Entity with the column names as your Bean/Entity field names.

**2) Now my doubt is that the join is done using the cid name. This name not appear as a property of my Address class. So what is it? Is it the name of a column belonging to the T_ADDRESS and that is not mapped by the entity class Address?**

Your Customer class contains a one-to-one mapping as :

```
...
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn (name=“cid”)
private Set<Address> addresses;
…
```

Using this mapping the ORM identifies which records in the Address table belongs to Customer with a specific ID;

Consider this Customers table :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cust_id  | Cust_firstname | Cust_lastname  |  Cust_email  |  Cust_mobile |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   101    |       XXXX     |    YYYYY         |xxx@xyz.com |  8282263131  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Above customers table is having one record with cust_id as 101.

Now Consider this Address Table :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id       |   street    |    suburb     |   city   |  zipcode |    cid    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1      |   streetX   |    AreaY      | cityZ    |  54726   |    101    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2      |   streetXA  |    AreaYB     | cityZS   |  60660   |    101    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your Address Table contains a *Foreign Key* column as **cid**, which is a good practice to have your foreign key columns in your Secondry table, And this is the default mechanism in Hibernate.

As you can see from the Address table, both the records with **id** as **1** and **2** belongs to the same Customer with **cust_id** as **101**

Answer (score 2):

1: Your assumption is correct

2: That's a [uni-directional one-to-many relation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29), meaning every **Customer** can have a list of **Address**es joined by a column named **cid** on the other table (foreign key.) So you can (directly) get **Address**es belonging to a **Customer** but not the other way around.

**Update (wish I had more SO reputation to comment)**

Some parts of the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879322/4440412) are incorrect:

> If you are not annotating your fields/properties of your Bean/Entity class with @Column then ORM provider (e.g. Hibernate) will create a table for the corresponding Bean/Entity with the column names as your Bean/Entity field names.

[JPA implementations such as Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/#jpa-provider) require some extra configuration to automatically generate/update tables for you. For Hibernate, you'll need to set `hbm2ddl.auto` property in persistence configuration.

> Your Customer class contains a one-to-one mapping

Obviously it contains a one-to-many mapping.

Comment: mmm I am not understanding what you mean when you say that I have to have the cid column in both the table. I think that I need to have the cid column into the T_ADDRESS class and this column have to contain the value of the primary key of a T_CUSTOMER row (as foreign key). Or not?

Comment: @AndreaNobili yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the hbm2ddl.auto point, I forgot to make a mention of it in my post. +1 for this